# Truncated Moodle user table

Tags: moodle

I am new in moodle , I forgotten the admin password and I tried to
change it from database using **Navicat** but it was encrypted , I
truncated the table .

**Please suggest me how can I solve this issue ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reset the admin password is to use the cli script admin/cli/reset_password.php. This works for all accounts using the 'manual' authentication method.

```
cd [path to Moodle install on server]/admin/cli
php reset_password.php
```

Then answer the questions that appear (username to reset, new password).

Comment: But I donot have any users cause I truncated the user table ' mdl_user'

Comment: Sorry, I was answering the first part of your question where you stated you wanted to reset the admin password. If this is a test site, then a clean install would now be the best bet. If there is real data on the site, then restoring from backup would be a good plan. Otherwise, you're going to have to manually recreate the user records.